# replace every other character in a string with php

Tags: php

In php is there a quick way of replacing every other character (non spaces) in a string with something else ? I searched around and haven't found a solution.

Take something like this:

```
    $str = "This is my example string!"
```

And end up with something like this:

```
    $result = "T*i* i* m* e*a*p*e s*r*n*!
```

Comment: Just curious; is your plan to use this in a query for searching purposes?

Comment: no the plan is to present somewhat minor hidden data back to the user ..  it's not sensitive info but we still just want to hide some of the text ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat the string as an `array`, loop through it and change the character using [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to check for parity:

```
<?php
$string = "This is my test string";

$length = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $string[$i] = $i % 2 === 0 ? $string[$i] : "*";
}
echo $string;
```

Result:

> `T*i* *s*m* *e*t*s*r*n*`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vv5V6)

Comment: Thanks, I like this one if I needed to look at each char but I picked the other answer because it was a done with a single command

Comment: @MikeQ definitely. I try to avoid regular expressions whenever possible but RomanPerekhrest is much more elegant!

Comment: I see, yeah they are "slower" (I suppose) and really can be bungled pretty easily..  Thanks for helping !

Comment: Well, you are right, the answer above was more difficult to handle and I went back to yours. I have an issue where the text was breaking the API so I ended up adding a preg_replace before I obfuscate it. So all in all, this is a simple thing but ended up very hard to debug due to the built in commands. Thank you for your feedback sir!

Answer (score 4):

Simple **`preg_replace()`** solution:

```
$str = "This is my example string!";
$result = preg_replace('/(\S)\S/', '$1*', $str);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
T*i* i* m* e*a*p*e s*r*n*!
```

---

- `\S` - stands for non-whitespace character